# Attempting to write to text file from local HTTP server

Tags: c

I'm using a local server generated with a C script to simply take in data from a client and write it to a text file. The text file ends up blank every time. It's probably some silly mistake but I can't seem to crack it, sorry if my inexperience is showing a bit too much here. The following is in main, and the rest of the code works great (opening server, receiving/printing client data to terminal).

```
    while(1)
    {
        FILE *f = fopen("data.txt", "w");
        if (f == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error opening file\n");
        }
        printf("\n+++++++ Waiting for new connection ++++++++\n\n");
        if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
        {
            perror("In accept");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        char buffer[30000] = {0};
        valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 30000);
        char str[256];
        sprintf(str, "%ld", valread);
        fputs(str,f);
        fprintf(f,"\n");
        fflush(f);
        printf("%s\n",buffer );
        write(new_socket , hello , strlen(hello));
        close(new_socket);
        fclose(f);
    }
```

Comment: what is the type of `hello` ? Is it a variable ? I guess its `"hello"`. `write(new_socket , hello , strlen(hello));` --> `write(new_socket , "hello" , strlen("hello") + 1);`

Comment: Looks to me you are writing *the number of bytes read* rather than the buffer (string) you got from the socket?

Comment: it's defined as char *hello = "Data Received";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you are looking at the file while the server runs, don't you?

Then you loop is most probably waiting in the called `accept()` for a client to connect. At this point of your program the file is opened by `fopen("data.txt", "w")` that creates the file if it doesn't exists, and truncates it if it exists. In either case the file seems to be there but is empty.

To solve this, you have several options:

1. You create a new file name on each turn of the loop. This way the old contents will not be overwritten by new contents.
2. You open the file after `accept()` returns. This way the file will be opened, written and closed in just a short period, not noticeable by a human.

BTW, your construct:

```
    char str[256];
    sprintf(str, "%ld", valread);
    fputs(str,f);
    fprintf(f,"\n");
```

is quite complicated. This is much clearer and has no need for a user provided buffer:

```
    fprintf(f, "%ld\n", valread);
```